# Upgrade from v10 to v12 - AzureSDK JS

Tags: javascript, azure-sdk

I am trying to upgrade my code from v10 to v12 but have no idea on how to go forward. Can someone help me out with it please?

```
import {
    Aborter,
    AnonymousCredential,
    BlobUploadCommonResponse,
    BlockBlobURL,
    StorageURL,
    uploadBrowserDataToBlockBlob
} from '@azure/storage-blob';

import { Upload } from '../types/models';

const CREDENTIALS = new AnonymousCredential();
const PIPELINE = StorageURL.newPipeline(CREDENTIALS);

export function uploadToAzure(upload: Upload, blob: Blob, options: {} = {}): Promise<BlobUploadCommonResponse> {
    const blockBlobURL = new BlockBlobURL(upload.BlobURL, PIPELINE);

    return uploadBrowserDataToBlockBlob(Aborter.none, blob, blockBlobURL, options);
}
```

This is what I have done.

```
import {
    Aborter,
    AnonymousCredential,
    BlobUploadCommonResponse,
    BlobServiceClient
    uploadBrowserData,
    newPipeline
} from '@azure/storage-blob';

import { Upload } from '../types/models';

const CREDENTIALS = new AnonymousCredential();
const PIPELINE = newPipeline(CREDENTIALS);

export function uploadToAzure(upload: Upload, blob: Blob, options: {} = {}): Promise<BlobUploadCommonResponse> {
    const blockBlobURL = new BlobServiceClient(upload.BlobURL, PIPELINE);

    return uploadBrowserData(blob, options);
}
```

Where does blockBlobURL value gets passed into as opposed to the old code? Thanks.

Please advice.

Comment: Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs

Comment: I did. Coulnt find a proper update guide

Comment: Could you tell me what do you wan to know? If you want to know more about the sdk, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/?view=azure-node-latest

Answer (score 1):

In v12 of the @azure/storage-blob SDK you can directly instantiate the `BlockBlobClient` with your URL that contains a SAS token.

```js
import { BlockBlobClient } from "@azure/storage-blob";

export function uploadToAzure(blobUrl: string , blob: Blob) {
  const client = new BlockBlobClient(blobUrl);
  return client.uploadBrowserData(blob);
}
```

The blob url with SAS token is provided as the first parameter when instantiating the `BlockBlobClient`. It is no longer required to pass in the `AnonymousCredential` since this will be used by default if no credential object is provided.

Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#blockblobclient-string--storagesharedkeycredential---anonymouscredential---tokencredential--storagepipelineoptions-